# Circular Saw Outer Washer Clamp Not Fitting with Metal Cutting Blade

Tags: circular-saw

I have a 7 inch Craftsman circular saw. I'm replacing the rip cut blade that came with it, with a new Norton Blufire metal cutting blade. The issue is the new blade is thicker so now the outer clamp washer won't fit over the housing and lock in place.

Is the normal? Is that washer optional?

Not sure what to do and don't want to make a drastic stupid mistake.

Here's the blade.

[image]

How the outer washer clamp is supposed to fit on the housing.

[image]

When you place the blade in the saw, the washer won't lock into the housing. Even if I turn it over, it doesn't really fit. It fits slightly, but it doesn't seem secure... or has room for error.

[image]

Comment: Wait — is that a grinder blade you’re trying to run in a saw? Don’t.

Comment: Which Norton Blufire blade specifically are you trying to use?

Comment: I'm using a 7 inch diameter, 3/32 inch thick, Type 01/41 blade used for cutting metal and used for circular saws.

Comment: A typical Craftsman home circular saw is not really intended for cutting metal.  Consider a hacksaw with a metal-cutting blade?

Comment: Ok. I can try that, but why doesn't the blade I purchased work? Can you confirm that the washer is required?

Comment: @ptownbro You're using the wrong parts with the equipment. It is expected to not fit. And yes, the washer is required. If they are optional, they wouldn't be there in the first place.

Comment: **If** the part we can't see has a diamond-shaped projection, which it probably doesn't, then the diamond-shaped center could be knocked out of the blade and things would fit closer. But I suspect the saw is not one of those that do.

Comment: What’s the model number of the saw?

Comment: Wrong kind of blade.  Go get yourself a metal-cutting diamond coated blade. Example" https://www.homedepot.com/p/RIDGID-7-in-Metal-Cutting-Diamond-Blade-HD-LMC70/204202535

Comment: @Huesmann -- setting expectations, I've been spectacularly disappointed by the performance of those Ridgid metal cutting blades (in a grinder) when compared to normal metal grinder disks. We still don't know if Craftsman recommends cutting metal with that saw, and given the plastic blade guard, my gut says no.

Comment: Okay. Thanks everyone for the input! Based on your recommendations, I gave up on using the circular saw and bought a $40 angular grinder saw which was able to cut the bar I was trying to cut. I also tried a diamond blade which fit, but the cut wasn't as clean as the angular saw. Thanks again everyone! Much appreciated.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I didn't say a grinder disc wouldn't work better, it's just that the thickness makes it the wrong kind of blade for the circular saw.  In the right tool, a grinder disc works!

Comment: I note that you've already switched to a grinder, but for future reference by other visitors, the [product listing page for your Norton Bluefire 01/41](https://www.nortonabrasives.com/en-us/product/bluefire-rightcut-ao-type-0141-right-angle-cut-wheel) specifically states that it's for use on a grinder and makes no mention of circular saws.